# MySQL How do I use a foreign key to identify a column in another table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the name of the customer who has the largest remaining principal.

In my DB   `loans.customer_id` is a foreign key referring to `customers.customer_id`;

These are the create statements:

```
    CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mortgages` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
```

USE `mortgages` ;

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mortgages`.`customers` (
      `customer_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `customer_name` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
      `customer_address` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
       `customer_email` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`))
     ENGINE = InnoDB;


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mortgages`.`loans` (
      `loan_id` INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `original_principal` DOUBLE NULL,
      `remaining_principal` DOUBLE NULL,
      `princiapl_paid` DOUBLE AS (original_principal - remaining_principal),
       `interest_paid` DOUBLE NULL,
      `customer_id` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`loan_id`),
      INDEX `fk_loans_customers_idx` (`customer_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_loans_customers`
        FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`)
        REFERENCES `mortgages`.`customers` (`customer_id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

These are the insert statements I used:

```
 INSERT INTO customers VALUES
    (default, 'Joe', '1313 Mockingbird Ln, Transylvania, PA 19666', 
    'jsmith@munsters.com'),
    (default, 'Jane', '123 Heaven Blvd, Cloud City, MA 00911', 'doejd@aol.com'),
    (default, 'Mike', '230860, Club Rd., New York City, NY 10108', 'mikejones@nightclub.com'), 

     INSERT INTO loans VALUES
    (default, 245000.00, 198232.21, default, 21833.25, 1),
    (default, 708921.50, 551123.80, default, 880082.99, 2),
    (default, 99000.00, 1001.12, default, 4591.12, 3),
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT customers.customer_name, loans.customer_id
from customers, loans
where (loans.remaining_principal=(SELECT MAX(loans.remaining_principal) FROM loans))
```

this displays ALL of the customer names next to `customer_id` of the MAX

What I want is to display  ONE customer name, who has the `customer_id` of the MAX

What I'm getting is:

| customer_name | customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| Joe | 2 |
| jane | 2 |
| Mike | 2 |

What I want to get is:

| customer_name | customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| jane | 2 |

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the `CREATE` statements of the involved tables as well as `INSERT` statements that populate them with the sample data that produced you current output and should produce the output you want.

Comment: An `ORDER BY` should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a cross join that combines every row from the customers with every row from the loans, so of course there's also a row for every customer combined with the maximum loan.

Use a proper inner join instead to just combine the loans and customers which actually belong together.

```
SELECT co.customer_name,
       lo.customer_id
       FROM customers co
            INNER JOIN loans lo
                       ON lo.customer_id = co.customer_id
       WHERE lo.remaining_principal = (SELECT max(li.remaining_principal)
                                              FROM loans li);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1304c2236c7232e6e81121c103b4a090)

The `WHERE` clause can stay like it is, though it'll give you more than one customer should there be more than one customer sharing the same maximum loan. I don't know, if you want that or what the secondary criteria to chose one customer from them would be then, so I cannot address this further.

Comment: Thank you so much! I hadn't even considered that there could be two customers sharing the same max loan, but that's even better. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a couple sub-queries:

```
SELECT customer_name, customer_id
FROM customers
where customer_id = (
    SELECT customer_id FROM loans WHERE remaining_principal = (
        SELECT MAX(remaining_principal) FROM loans))
```

Comment: Thank you, that works but it also adds an extra row that displays "null | null". It's acceptable for my purposes but some other people gave me answers that didn't include that extra row. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply:

```
SELECT loans.customer_id, customers.customer_name
FROM loans
JOIN customers 
ON loans.customer_id = customers.customer_id
WHERE (loans.remaining_principal = (SELECT MAX(loans.remaining_principal) FROM loans));
```

JOIN lets you grab that name from the customers table as an add-on to the main data which is the loans table.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT MAX(remaining_principal),customer_name,customer_id FROM Customers`

I hope this helps. Also Try to avoid `principle_paid = original_principal - remaining_principal`, It's `remaining_principal = original_principal - principle_paid`

Comment: Yes, you are right, that does make more logical sense.

Comment: upvote and mark it as answer if it is helpful